# Cygwin64 does not show my desktop directories

Tags: permissions, cygwin-64

I try to get cygwin64 show my desktop directories.
I use the following command to change to this directory:
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Default/Desktop

But when I then use ls I get nothing.

I suspect this is a permission problem, but failed to overcome it.